# Fast fmt.Scanf() of a large UTF-8 string

Tags: performance, input, go

I have a string of about 8000000 UTF-8 characters. Scanning it via `fmt.Scanf()` takes about 10 seconds, how can I do it faster? I have a Go wrapper for C `scanf()` function that was written by my teacher as a workaround for some bugs in Go's fmt.Scanf(), it works in 1-2 seconds, but I don't like using side packages for such simple tasks. Could you suggest some faster way of reading strings in pure Go?

Comment: What kind of scanning are you doing? Looking for a particular type of number? If you want something fast it is good to know the specific problem - otherwise stick with something general and proven.

Comment: @Floris What I'm scanning is "%s %c %c". I'm going to iterate through the read string's runes, but I have to know those two characters that come after beforehand. So I have to scan that string and store it into memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. `bufio` works much faster (as it's buffered, and `fmt`'s functions are not, and it doesn't parse anything):

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
str, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')   // Like fmt.Scanf("%s", &str), but faster
var x, y rune
fmt.Fscanf(reader, "%c %c", &x, &y) // I need to read something else
                                    // (see comments for the question)
                                    // It's easy, as I can use fmt.Fscanf
```

...even faster that that C `scanf()` wrapper.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster if you'd just use indexing? Am I missing something? `[]rune(str)[0]` and `[1]` should do it completely without `Fscanf`

Comment: @nemo I don't do anything with the read string by calling `fmt.Fscanf()`. My intention was to read "%s %c %c" (see comments for the question). So first I read that %s using fast reader, and then I read two space-separated characters using slow `fmt.Fscanf()`.

Comment: @nemo, wouldn't using `[]rune(str)[0]` first make an array of `int32`s? From the spec I gather `rune` is an alias to `int32`, and the string is defined to hold UTF-8 bytes, which is a variable-length encoding. For 8000000 UTF-8 characters this might be an expensive operation.

Comment: @kostix Yes, the conversion is done using `runtime.stringslicetorune`. However, he doesn't need to convert the full string but only the first characters. I'm pretty sure that `fmt.*scanf` also operates on runes and my attempt was to get rid of the Scanf call as it parses only two characters and a blank, which is easily done with indexing. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @nemo, that's interesting. In theory, your approach to the problem is sensible, but implementing it would either require lazy evaluation (the runtime should convert only that many runes to fullfill the indexing request(s) on the resulting slice) or runtime optimization (the analyzer could see we're only accessing that many runes and produce the code perform only a minimal conversion). Unfortunately I lack the necessary skills to see how it's really implemented.

Comment: @kostix You could just convert the slice you need? Like `[]rune(str[0:12])`